# Load html from Servlet with $().load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a new jquery tab with HTML from the server:

```
$("#tab"+username).load("/lod1/ProfileServlet",{user:"username"},function(){
            //fill in template with user's info
            console.log("it worked");
 });
```

servlet:

```
    System.out.println("USERNAME HERE");
    RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/profileTemplate.html");
    req.forward(request, response);
```

In the browser I see the confirmation 'it worked' so it seems that the request was successful. But on the server I don't see the output "USERNAME HERE" and "#tabusername" is not populated with the html requested(which I can confirm is in the right place):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div>
    <h1>USERS PROFILE AND THEME</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Is "/lod1/ProfileServlet" a GET or a POST? As data is provided, you are calling with a POST.

Comment: it's in doGet(), I moved the html page out of webinf and changed the url of .load to '/lod1/profileTemplate.html' removed the data and it worked. But say I wanted to return the page via servlet ? Why didn't it work like they say here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036130/how-to-return-an-html-document-from-java-servlet

Comment: ah: "Request Method

The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed."

Comment: thanks @jordiburgos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your servlet is listening for a GET, you can't pass the data to `.load()` as the second data parameter.

Use this to call the servlet with a GET:

```
$("#tab"+username).load("/lod1/ProfileServlet?user="+username, function() {
    //fill in template with user's info
    console.log("it worked");
});
```